# Strange behaviour with xjc.exe when renaming XSD file

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xjc

I have a set of XSD files:

```
635949212012288836_input.xml.xsd
635949212012288836_input.xml_app1.xsd
635949212012288836_input.xml_app2.xsd
635949212012288836_input.xml_app3.xsd
635949212012288836_input.xml_app4.xsd
xml.xsd
```

The first file (main file), 635949212012288836_input.xml.xsd, contains imports of the other 5 five files:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xxxx.com/soa/emf/GLHR-MLM-CURD/envelope/" schemaLocation="635949212012288836_input.xml_app2.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xxxx.com/soa/emf/common/header" schemaLocation="635949212012288836_input.xml_app1.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xxxx.com/soa/emf/service/GLHR-MLM-CURD" schemaLocation="635949212012288836_input.xml_app3.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xxxx.com/soa/emf/common/body" schemaLocation="635949212012288836_input.xml_app4.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml.xsd"/>
```

When I run the following to generate the Java source codes into the "generated" folder:

```
xjc.exe -d generated *.xsd
```

It runs successfully.

If I rename the first file, 635949212012288836_input.xml.xsd, to any of the below names (putting an extra "x" in the name),

```
635949212012288836_xinput.xml.xsd
635949212012288836_ixnput.xml.xsd
635949212012288836_inputx.xml.xsd
```

and run xjc.exe again, I will hit errors about some names cannot be resolved in the file 635949212012288836_input.xml_app2.xsd.

However, if I rename the first file as follow (putting an extra "i" instead):

```
635949212012288836_iinput.xml.xsd
```

and run xjc.exe again, it will run successfully!

What could be the reason for this abnormal behavior?

Note that the other files have no reference to the first file.

Thanks.

Comment: did you delete the generated files before generating again?

Comment: Yes I did delete before I re-generated.